# How can I stream .flv files in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, flash, iis, streaming, httphandler

I have a working solution on an IIS6, which I made using this guide: [FLV Flash video streaming with ASP.NET 2.0, IIS and HTTP handler](http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/kfra/archive/2006/10/04/50003.aspx)

The app is basically a FLV Player, but streaming is essential to it.

Now, one of our customers is running IIS7 and the streaming doesn't work, so I was hoping that someone in here would now how do handle this.

Comment: What does the log file look like when the request is made ?

Answer (score 0):

The IIS could be missing the MIME type declaration and not serving the fla files. Look at this post for a possible solution: http://flassari.is/2010/05/flv-and-f4v-files-not-found-on-iis/